# want to make the search bar float to left side

Tags: html, css

want to make the search bar float to left side and the icon is on right side and when it float to below css property should not have to disturb.

```css
#search_bar .container-2 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
}

#search_bar .container-2 input#search {
  width: 52px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #2b303b;
  border: none;
  font-size: 10pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  color: #aac500;
  margin-top: -13px;
  padding-left: 45px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: width .55s ease;
  -moz-transition: width .55s ease;
  -ms-transition: width .55s ease;
  -o-transition: width .55s ease;
  transition: width .55s ease;
}

#search_bar .container-2 input#search::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #65737e;
}

#search_bar .container-2 input#search:-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  color: #65737e;
}

#search_bar .container-2 input#search::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  color: #65737e;
}

#search_bar .container-2 input#search:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #65737e;
}

#search_bar .container-2 .icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: 17px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #6bbb06;
}

#search_bar .container-2:hover .icon {
  color: #aac500;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<div id="search_bar">
  <div class="container-2">
    <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..." />
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, post a link to the site.

Comment: Could you clarify the last part of your statement; "*and when it float to below css property should not have to disturb*"?

Comment: www.arstechs.com @izulito

Comment: you can see that at my website @UncaughtTypeError   arstechs.com

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't clarify the statement any further. The issue needs to be demonstrated in the problem statement itself by providing an Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise the question is technically "off topic" and should be closed. Improving the quality of the question itself, *by reproducing the issue and clarifying your statements*, amongst other things, will encourage high-quality answers that you (as well as the site, and the community, as a whole) seeks.

Comment: i want that the search bar should float from right to left side in above of the signin buttons

Comment: have you visited my site

Comment: help me.........